# Downloading file with vue-resourse destroys .xls file output format

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to download .xls file via API but output file format is incorrect, it looks like this:
[image]

here is my code:

```
exportData: function() {
  let items_ids = [];
  this.$refs['vue-items-reports-table'].selectedRows.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    var x = arrayItem.id;
    items_ids.push(arrayItem.id);
  });
  this.$http.get('/api/items-reports/', {'params': {'file_format': this.export_format, 'items': items_ids.toString()}}).then(function(response){
    let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type:response.headers.get('content-type')});
    filename = response.headers.map['content-disposition'][0].split('filename=')[1];
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = filename.replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
    link.click();
  })
}
```

File format is correct when I put endpoint URL directly in the browser so a problem is in the Vue part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `vue-resource` for HTTP calls.

Try using `reponse.blob()` (it returns a promise) and use that result for the download.